# Switching the Order of Summations

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Under what conditions is it okay to switch the order of two nested infinite summations? I am working on a proof in order to show that a particular set function is a probability measure. In order to show countable additivity, I need to switch the order of two summations. The only other info I have is that it is a set function of a sum of a sequence of probability measures defined on a complete probability space. I am not told if anything is positive, bounded, etc. I do remember reading somewhere that this is ok to do if the sums are absolutely convergent - does the fact that I am in a complete probability space guarantee me that?

Any assistance you could provide would be most helpful.

Comment: I've been told here that in general switching any sorts of limits, including infinite sums, is generally going to be messy.

Comment: @dfeuer Switching limits for finite sums ain't bad.

Comment: For infinite sums, though, messy or not, what theorems, etc. can I use to justify doing it?

Comment: As long as you are summing non-negative real numbers, such as probabilities, you can sum them in any order you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out, and I think it depends on whether your r.v.'s are positive (in which case, you can use Monotone Convergence Theorem) or if they are dominated by an integrable r.v. (In which case, you can use the Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem). And when they are probabilities, which they are in this problem, they are positive, and hence the Monotone Convergence Theorem applies.

Comment: Well, @egreg MSE won't let me vote for my own post.